# Button click on second layout doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

What I want is: Press a button and then the app goes to another layout ( page).
On this page you press a button and then some text is shown in a textbox.
I made a activity for each layout.

I get this error
 E/AndroidRuntime(862): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method calculateKfactor(View) in the activity class tweaks.engineering.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'btnCalculateKf'

This is my code on my main activity to go to the other layout this works!:)

Updated MainActivity

```
public void  Sheetmetal (View view){
    if (view == mbtnSheetmetal){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheetmetal);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SheetmetalActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
}
```

This is my code for the second activity: SheetmetalActivity

```
package tweaks.engineeringsheet;

import tweaks.engineering.R;
import tweaks.engineering.R.id;
import tweaks.engineering.R.layout;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SheetmetalActivity extends Activity{

    //text box define
    EditText mtxtKfactor;

    //Button define
    Button mbtnCalculateKf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheetmetal);

        //connect mtxt"name" to txt"name"
        mtxtKfactor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtKfactor);

        //connect mbtn"name" to btn"name"
        mbtnCalculateKf = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculateKf);
    }


    public void calculatekfactor(View view){
        if (view == mbtnCalculateKf){       

            mtxtKfactor.setText("works");
            mtxtKfactor.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

        } //end if
    }//end class
} // end program
```

Comment: Did you set onClick in the XML or are you missing the OnClickListener?

Comment: I have a button on the first layout to go to te second layout this works. But a button to run the void CalculateKfactor doesn't work.

Comment: I have set the onclick in the button property to CalculateKfactor. Do i need an OnClicklistener? My English programming vocabulary is'nt good so i hope you understand me

Comment: Can you post the layout for the button?

Comment: this is from the xml <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCalculateKf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="calculateKfactor"
        android:text="@string/button_calculate" />

Comment: Your onClick is calling calculateKfactor, but you named the method CalculateKfactor.

Comment: In the button property the C is Uppercase and in the xml lowercase a changed it in te xml to uppercase but this didn't work. i will change both C to lowercase maybe this works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the onclick of your button calls a method called **calculateKfactor**
Make your method public, or it won't find it.
Remember that without setting a visibility modifier you're on package visibility and not public visibility

**EDIT**

You say you go to the second activity (where your method resides) doing this:

```
 public void  Sheetmetal (View view){
    if (view == mbtnSheetmetal){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheetmetal); 
        }
   }
```

This is changing the layout of the main activity, so when you see your button you are still in the first activity, and when you click he searches your method in mainActivity.
To start another activity follow these steps:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourSecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I understand i changed everything to lowercase See my updated code and the .xml this is my second layout .xml for the            
Button
android:id="@+id/btnCalculateKf"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:onClick="calculatekfactor"
android:text="@string/button_calculate"

Comment: Ok I wasn't understanding quite good your problem, you must put also that method in the second activity, else it won't find it. if you don't want to repeat it then define the content of your method somewhere else, but remember that the method you name in you layout MUST be present in the activity else it won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I understand this. I the onclick property of my button in the second layout the same method name as i am using in the second activity. And i have added the second activity to the manifest. Still the program is searching for the method in the main activity. I have added the method to the main activity and then the erros Skipped 45 Frames! the application may be doing to much work on its main thread.

Comment: Your not changing the activity, you're just changing the layout!!  public void  Sheetmetal (View view){
    if (view == mbtnSheetmetal){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheetmetal); 
        }
   }

Comment: you must create your second activity, then inflate it with your layout! that's why it's still searching in your main activity!!!

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. See my updated code for the main activity. Is this good? it now says it can't find the Type SheetmetalAcivity Wich is my second activity

Comment: remove this line setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheetmetal); before you start the activity. Have you got any eclipse error on your activity name where you create the intent?

Comment: from wich activity should i delete the line setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheetmetal);  and yes i have an error on the activity name :  it can't find the Type SheetmetalAcivity

Comment: If you're having an error so check if it is imported  and if not just import it, remove that line from this method : public void  Sheetmetal (View view) in your first activity

Comment: you're welcome, but try next time to test more stuff so people won't downvote your questions ^^

Comment: i tried allot myself only it's a very different programming langauge then visual basic. so i didn't know the correct search terms to find my answers. Thanks for the new experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the calculateKFactor function in main activity (via a button click) you have a few options:

1) move that function into main activity from sheet metal activity

2) if you need to use the function in both activities... for the activity that doesn't have the calculateKFactor function within it, you could have a function that handles the initial button click, then calls the public function from the second file (the function would also have to be static)..

3) Alternative method, if you need to use the function in both activities... create a parent activity that each of the two activities extend..

May also want to check your capitalization.. the error has calculate in lower case but SheetmetalActivity has the Calculate in upper case..

Comment: Why do i want to move calculateKfactor to main activity if i can seperate the activity's for each layout?

Comment: in the error is stated that it cannot find the method in the main activity but i moved it to main activity and then i get te error: 100 frames skipped maybe to much running on your main activity

Comment: The original error states that the method wasn't visible to main activity.. that's why moving it there would help with that.  As far as the second error, not sure without seeing more.

Comment: I will respond to you  in the morning. Good night from the netherlands

Comment: goodnight! hang in there. android is great, relatively simple once you get the hang of it. It is also very well documented online (usually the best reference for help!).

Comment: Is it possible to send the program to one of you. I am realy getting the feeling that i am missing something really easy to solve. But i can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the second Activity in your Menifest file? This is an easy mistake to miss

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I missed this. I have googled how to add the activity to the manifest. It is in there now. Still got the error could not find method in main activity. I have added the method to the main activity. Now this error occurs: Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I wan't that it can find the method in the second activity.